# Connect first and last point on ListPolarPlot

Tags: plotting

I have this function that creates a plot in Wolfram Mathematica:
`ListPolarPlot[{98.00000, 93.99300, 83.60000, 67.50000, 48.72000,  30.34000, 15.75000, 5.06000, 0.96000, 0.00000, 1.23000, 6.05000,  17.25000, 33.21000, 51.62000, 70.50000, 85.36000, 95.93100,  99.50000, 94.96200, 85.36000, 69.00000, 49.30000, 30.75000,  15.50000, 5.06000, 0.93000, 0.00000, 1.20000, 5.61000, 17.75000,  32.80000, 51.04000, 69.75000, 85.36000, 94.96200, 99.00000},  Joined -> True]`

What I want to do, is to connect the first and the last point on the graph. Is there a way to do it via this function? I've searched for it, but didn't find a thing to be honest.

There is a screenshot of the result that I have now:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
here is your list:

```
lst = {98.00000, 93.99300, 83.60000, 67.50000, 48.72000, 30.34000, 
   15.75000, 5.06000, 0.96000, 0.00000, 1.23000, 6.05000, 17.25000, 
   33.21000, 51.62000, 70.50000, 85.36000, 95.93100, 99.50000, 
   94.96200, 85.36000, 69.00000, 49.30000, 30.75000, 15.50000, 
   5.06000, 0.93000, 0.00000, 1.20000, 5.61000, 17.75000, 32.80000, 
   51.04000, 69.75000, 85.36000, 94.96200, 99.00000};
```

Let us do the following:

```
lst1 = Join[lst, {First[lst]}];
ListPolarPlot[lst1, Joined -> True, DataRange -> {0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

yielding

[image]

Have fun!